# How to convert the following Objective-C code into swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I don't know how to convert the following Objective-C code into Swift. How should I do ?

```
-(void)layoutSubviews{

    for (UIView *view in self.subviews) {

        NSString *viewClass = NSStringFromClass([view class]);
        if (![viewClass isEqualToString:@"UITabBarButton"]) continue;

        CGFloat buttonX = buttonIndex * buttonW;
        if (buttonIndex >= 2) {
            buttonX += buttonW;
        }

        view.frame = CGRectMake(buttonX, buttonY, buttonW, buttonH);
        buttonIndex ++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider this link : https://objectivec2swift.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for view in self.subviews {
  guard view is UITabBarButton else {
    continue
  }

  var buttonX = buttonIndex * buttonW
  if buttonIndex >= 2 {
    buttonX += buttonW
  }
  view.frame = CGRect(x: buttonX, y: buttonY, width: buttonW, height: buttonH)
  buttonIndex += 1
}
```

Comment: `UITabBarButton` is a private class so you cannot reference it directly if you want app store approval. That is why the code in the question checks using a string comparison.

Comment: good point i was just converting the code over syntactically i didnt check it in xcode

Comment: so could you please tell me what should I do?

Comment: usually if a class is private (as rob pointed out) it will be for good reason and shouldn't be accessed. it seems youre simply trying to populate a tabbar? if so you should rely on the api for uitabbar to do that for you during initialisation - usually i just do so through storyboard but in the morning i will post a programatic solution - if this is what you are trying to achieve that is